# jQuery class change function only for first input?

Tags: jquery, class

why my script only working for first input with class `.dodanyikoniec` ?

My script:

```
$(".dodanyikoniec").change(function() {
var valSplit = $(this).val().split("-");
var valDzien = valSplit[0];
var valMiesiac = valSplit[1];
var valRok = valSplit[2];

if (valRok != undefined)
        {
        if (valDzien.length == 2) {
        $(this).val(valRok+"-"+valMiesiac+"-"+valDzien);
        }
        }

});
```

Comment: are you adding those text boxes dynamically

Comment: if you are adding those textboxes dynamically, then use event delegation... `$(document).on('change', '.dodanyikoniec', function(){...})`

Comment: yes my inputs are added dynamically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**event delegation**](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) if your input has been added dynamically so the change event can bind to these newly added input elements:

```
$(document).on('change', '.dodanyikoniec', function(){
     // Your code here
})
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/awesome/BNtMe/

```
$(".dodanyikoniec").change(function() {
  var _this = $(this)
  var valSplit = _this.val().split("-");
  var valDzien = valSplit[0];
  var valMiesiac = valSplit[1];
  var valRok = valSplit[2];

  if (valRok != undefined) {
    if (valDzien.length == 2) {
      _this.val(valRok+"-"+valMiesiac+"-"+valDzien);
    }
  }
});
```